# Does jqGrid support milliseconds in "datefmt"?

Tags: jqgrid

One of my columns contains dates and is sortable. I unsuccessfully tried to use `datefmt: 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.sss'` and `d/m/Y H:i:s.u` in the column model to describe to jqGrid how to sort the column.

An example of the actual data to be sorted is `07/10/2011 03:08:32.454`.

Of course, the column's `sorttype` is `'date'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this as a bug in jqGrid, and it will be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to post date/time information in some non-localized format. For example in this one:

```
2011-05-29T23:36:41.1470055+02:00
```

Such date format is already sortable. To convert `myDate` variable of the `DateTime` in the format you can use under .NET the "o" foratter:

```
myDate.ToString ("o", new CultureInfo ("en-us", true))
```

**To display** the date in the 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.sss' format you can use about the following  [custom formetter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter):

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var regexp = "([0-9]{4})(-([0-9]{2})(-([0-9]{2})" +
                 "(T([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(:([0-9]{2})(\.([0-9]+))?)?" +
                 "(Z|(([-+])([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})))?)?)?)?",
        d = cellvalue.match(new RegExp(regexp));
    return d[5] + '/' + d[3] + '/' + d[1] + ' ' + d[7] + ':' + d[8] + ':' + d[10] +
          '.'+ d[12];
}
```